# How to create a page navigation partial view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I have a `PaginatedList<T>` class inheriting from `List<T>` in an ASP.NET Core app that my controllers and views use to render paginated content:

```
public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T>
{
    public int PageNumber { get; private set; } = 1;    // page index

    public int PageSize { get; private set; } = 25;     // item count in each page

    public int TotalCount { get; private set; }         // total items in all pages

    public int PageCount { get; private set; }          // total page count

    public bool HasPreviousPage => PageNumber > 1;

    public bool HasNextPage => PageNumber < PageCount;

    public int From => PageSize * (PageNumber - 1) + 1; // index of first item in page

    public int To => From + Count - 1;                  // index of last item in page

    //Method bodies omitted for brevity
    public static async Task<PaginatedList<T>> CreateAsync(
             IQueryable<T> source, int pageSize = 25, int pageNumber = 1) {..}

    private PaginatedList(
       List<T> items, int count, int pageSize = 25, int pageNumber = 1) {..}
}
```

<sub>*Code based on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-6.0#add-paging-to-students-index) with additional validation.*</sub>

I have noticed that almost all of my views serving paginated lists have the same page navigation UI. (For all entities in the app like `Person`, `Book`, etc.):

```
@model PaginatedList<Person>

@*View-specific code here...*@

<nav aria-label="Page Navigation">

    @if (Model.Count > 1)
    {
        @* Display the range of entities displayed *@
        <div class="text-center text-muted my-2">
            <em>Showing @Model.From to @Model.To out of @Model.TotalCount</em>
        </div>
    }

    <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
        @if (Model.HasPreviousPage || Model.HasNextPage)
        {
            @if (Model.HasPreviousPage)
            {
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a asp-controller="Person"
                       asp-action="Index" 
                       asp-route-repoId="@Model.RepoId" 
                       asp-route-page="@(Model.PageNumber - 1)" 
                       title="Previous" class="page-link" aria-label="Previous">
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>&laquo;
                    </a>
                </li>
            }
            else
            {
                <li class="page-item disabled">
                    <a class="page-link" tabindex="-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>&laquo;
                    </a>
                </li>
            }
            <li class="page-item active" aria-current="page">
                 <a class="page-link" href="#">@Model.PageNumber</a>
            </li>

            @if (Model.HasNextPage)
            {
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a 
                       asp-controller="Person"
                       asp-action="Index"
                       asp-route-repoId="@Model.RepoId" 
                       asp-route-page="@(Model.PageNumber + 1)" title="Next" class="page-link" aria-label="Next">
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>&raquo;
                    </a>
                </li>
            }
            else
            {
                <li class="page-item disabled">
                    <a class="page-link" tabindex="-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>&raquo;
                    </a>
                </li>
            }
        }
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I would like to extract this to a partial view called `_PageNav.cshtml`. But there are two things I'm not quite sure about:

1. The `PaginatedList<T>` class is generic and I cannot have a partial view with a model called `PaginatedList<T>` with an open generic parameter `T`. One possible solution I can think of is writing a non-generic interface called `IPaginatedList` that has all the properties required for page navigation and then have `PaginatedList<T>` implement it. This is because the navigation UI does not need to know anything about the items in the list. Then I can use `IPaginatedList` as the model for my partial view:

```
public interface IPaginatedList
{
    public int PageNumber { get; }

    public int PageSize { get; }

    public int TotalCount { get; }

    public int PageCount { get; }

    public bool HasPreviousPage { get; }

    public bool HasNextPage { get; }

    public int From { get; }

    public int To { get; }
}
```

```
public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T>, IPaginatedList
{
 ...
}
```

`_PageNav.cshtml`:

```
@model IPaginatedList

@* Navigation UI *@
...
```

This would kind of solve the first issue.

2. The second issue is that each view with a paginated list has a different previous and next page link. (the area/controller/action name for the link and different route values):

```
@* Previous page link *@
<a asp-controller="Persons"
   asp-action="Index" 
   asp-route-repoId="@Model.RepoId" 
   asp-route-page="@(Model.PageNumber - 1)" 
   title="Previous" 
   class="page-link" 
   aria-label="Previous">
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>&laquo;
</a>

@* Next page link *@
<a asp-controller="Persons"
   asp-action="Index"
   asp-route-repoId="@Model.RepoId" 
   asp-route-page="@(Model.PageNumber + 1)" 
   title="Next" 
   class="page-link" 
   aria-label="Next">
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>&raquo;
</a>
```

The above would be the previous and next links for  the `Index` action of `PersonsController` (`Person` entity). This would change for another entity like `Book`.

Should I have a property for each link tag helper argument in my `PaginatedList<T>` like `ControllerName`, `ActionName`, etc.? Is there a better way?
Can this be solved with a custom tag-helper? What am I missing?

Comment: I use the page model... so @model YourSite.Pages.IndexModel.  (razor pages with view models...the partial uses the same model as the "body" partial I use)  When you pass your Iqueryable into your Paginatation class, you type it, and then cast it again on return: public PaginatedList<InventoryItem> PaginatedInventory { get; set; }   PaginatedInventory = await PaginatedList<InventoryItem>.CreateAsync(                Items,CurrentPageIndex, IntegerCurrentLimit);  So you really do need separate pagination partials for each different page/view model.

Comment: The PaginatedInventory object contains some of the parameters you need... such has HasPrevious, HasNext, etc... for instance in links I use the Page index for next/previous, like this for previous: asp-route-pageIndex="@(Model.PaginatedInventory.PageIndex - 1)"

Comment: Not a solution, but former PagedList.Mvc did exactly what you are trying to do. Please check https://github.com/dncuug/X.PagedList  for inspiration or use. 
BTW they used HTML helpers for the generic paging.

Answer (score 1):

I have solution for using tag helpers

```
public class PaginationTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        [HtmlAttributeName("onclick-method-name")]
        public string OnClick { get; set; }

        [HtmlAttributeName("current-page-index")]
        public int CurrentPage { get; set; }

        [HtmlAttributeName("end-page")]
        public int EndPage { get; set; }

        [HtmlAttributeName("start-page")]
        public int StartPage { get; set; }
        [HtmlAttributeName("total-page-count")]
        public int TotalPages { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Process
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <param name="output"></param>
        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            var onclickMethodFormat = OnClick + "({0})"; // 0 - pagenumber . 
            var onclickMethod = string.Empty;

            StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
            content.Append("<nav aria-label=\"Page navigation example\" class=\"pagin-holder clearfix\"> <ul class=\"pagination pagination-sm\">");

            if (EndPage > 1)
            {
                if (CurrentPage > 1)
                {
                    onclickMethod = string.Format(onclickMethodFormat, CurrentPage - 1);
                    content.Append("<li class=\"page-item\"> <a href=\"#\" class=\"page-link\"  onclick=\"" + onclickMethod + "\">Previous</a></li>");
                }

                for (var page = StartPage; page <= EndPage; page++)
                {
                    onclickMethod = string.Format(onclickMethodFormat, page);

                    if (page == CurrentPage)
                    {
                        content.Append("<li class=\"page-item active\"><a href=\"#\" class=\"page-link\"onclick=\"" + onclickMethod + "\">").Append(page).Append(" </a>");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        content.Append("<li class=\"page-item\"><a href=\"#\" class=\"page-link\"onclick=\"" + onclickMethod + "\">").Append(page).Append(" </a>");
                    }
                }

                if (CurrentPage < TotalPages)
                {
                    onclickMethod = string.Format(onclickMethodFormat, CurrentPage + 1);
                    content.Append("<li class=\"page-item\"> <a href=\"#\" class=\"page-link\" onclick=\"" + onclickMethod + "\">Next</a> </li>");
                }
            }
            output.Content.AppendHtml(content.ToString());
        }
    }
```

This is my custom pagination class

```
public class PagingInfo
    {
        public int PageIndex { get; set; }
        public int PageSize { get; set; }
       
        public string SortOrder { get; set; }
      
        public byte SortColumn { get; set; }
        public string SortColumnName { get; set; }
        public int TotalRecords { get; set; }
        public string SearchText { get; set; }
        public byte FilterByColumn { get; set; }
        public string FilterByColumnName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Pager
    {
        public Pager(long totalItems, int? page, int pageSize = 10)
        {
            // calculate total, start and end pages
            var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)totalItems / (decimal)pageSize);
            var currentPage = page != null ? (int)page : 1;
            var startPage = currentPage - 5;
            var endPage = currentPage + 4;
            if (startPage <= 0)
            {
                endPage -= (startPage - 1);
                startPage = 1;
            }
            if (endPage > totalPages)
            {
                endPage = totalPages;
                if (endPage > 10)
                {
                    startPage = endPage - 9;
                }
            }

            TotalItems = totalItems;
            CurrentPage = currentPage;
            PageSize = pageSize;
            TotalPages = totalPages;
            StartPage = startPage;
            EndPage = endPage;
        }

        public long TotalItems { get; set; }
        public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
        public int PageSize { get; set; }
        public int TotalPages { get; set; }
        public int StartPage { get; set; }
        public int EndPage { get; set; }
    }
```

Added tag helper in view:

```
<Pagination onclick-method-name="Index" current-page-index="Model.PagingInfo.CurrentPage" end-page="Model.PagingInfo.EndPage"
                            start-page="Model.PagingInfo.StartPage" total-page-count="Model.PagingInfo.TotalPages"></Pagination>
```

Comment: @Amal accept the answer if it's resolve your issue.